# Any open source back test engine using bloomberg tick-by-tick data?

Tags: bloomberg, algorithmic-trading

I have a back test on index futures to do. I've finished the test on 1-minute OHLC data and the result is OK. Further I want to opt our tick-by-tick data downloaded from Bloomberg.

I have browsed the internet and found that several trading platforms are available for such function but Bloomberg is not in the data source providers list. So I think these are not suitable for my case.

I'm wondering whether there is any open-source engine that I may embed to finish the test?

Comment: I would have thought most of these platform can accept custom data (through a file or data container for example). In that case it is just a matter of getting the data from Bloomberg via their API and forwarding the data in the right format to the platform.

Comment: So you have the tick-by-tick data already downloaded? Most of these platforms allow you to upload CSV files if that works. Have you tried it? Otherwise you can spend some time to write a custom connector/bridge from Bloomberg to an open source platform like Tradelink.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you start with `R` and check out the `quantmod`, `TTR` and `quantstrat` packages to name just a few. R also has a bare-bones API-calling function in the `Rbbg` package.

R allows for extensive backtesting, if you're willing to put in the work.

Also, one other point to note. Bloomberg does not provide very much tickdata via the API. You might get 60d. In all but a few very highly specialized cases, this is not enough data for robust statistical back-testing.

Comment: What do you mean by `extensive backtesting`?

Answer (score -1):

You may use [AlgoQuant](http://numericalmethod.com/blog/algoquant/) to download Bloomberg tick-by-tick data and then do backtesting with them. See this blog article:
http://numericalmethod.com/blog/2012/12/21/bloomberg-tick-by-tick-data-download/